# undefined method `click' for "2":String, Rails error when using Mechanize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, mechanize

```
class ScraperController < ApplicationController

 def show
  mechanize = Mechanize.new

  website = mechanize.get('https://website.com/')
  $max = 2
  $counter = 0
  $link_to_click = 2

  @names = []

  while $counter <= $max do
    @names.push(website.css('.memName').text.strip)
    website.link_with(:text => '2').text.strip.click
    $link_to_click += 1
    $counter += 1
  end
 end
end
```

I am trying to scrape 20 items off of each page and then click on the link at the bottom (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, etc.). However, I get the error as seen in the title which tells me that I cannot click the string. So it recognizes that the button '2' exists but will tell me if cannot click it. Ideally, once this is sorted out, I wanted to the use the $link_to_click variable as a way to replace the '2' so that it will increment each time but it always comes back as nil. I have also changed it to .to_s with the same result.

If I remove the click all together, it will scrape the same page 3 times instead of moving onto the next page. I have also removed the text.strip part before the .click and it will do the same thing. I have tried many variations but have had no luck.

I would really appreciate any advice you could offer.

Comment: (1) Why are you using globals? (2) `String#strip` returns a string and string's don't have `click` methods, what are you expecting `website.link_with(:text => '2').text.strip.click` to do?

Comment: @muistooshort I had tried both (out of desperation which is never good), if I do this `website.link_with(:text => $link_to_click).click` or `website.link_with(:text => 2).click` result in the error _undefined method `click' for nil:NilClass_

Comment: That's telling you that it isn't finding the link you're looking for, right?

Comment: What you said got me thinking, rereading the articles I was referencing and then I changed it to `website = website.link_with(:text => $link_to_click.to_s).click` (because it only worked as a string) and it printed out the first page, second and each one thereafter. Thank you so much for that, even for just forcing me to second (a lot more than second) guess myself.

Comment: You could covert that last comment to an answer, you're allowed to answer your own questions and it might help someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up reviewing the articles I was referencing to solve this and came to this conclusion.

I changed the website_link to `website = website.link_with(:text => $link_to_click.to_s).click` (because it only worked as a string) and it printed out the first page, second and each one thereafter.

These are the articles that I was referencing to learn how to do this.

http://docs.seattlerb.org/mechanize/GUIDE_rdoc.html

and

https://readysteadycode.com/howto-scrape-websites-with-ruby-and-mechanize